# How to bind multiple form elements to a single variable with the Play! framework

Tags: frameworks, playframework, playframework-1.x

I am using the Play! framework, version 1. I have a form with 3 different select elements for day, month and year. I want to bind these to the birth date of a user (public Date birthDate defined in class User). How can I do this? Thanks.

Comment: Tania, tagging question for Play framework with `playback` is like comparing Russia and color pencils -> doesn't make any sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create three setters getters in your class for day, month and year and update your date with these values. The best way to do that is to use joda date classes

```
public class MyClass {
    public DateMidnight birthDate;

    public int getBirthDateYear() {
        return birthDate.getYear();
    }
    public void setBirthDateYear(int year) {
        birthDate = birthDate.withYear(year);
    }
}
```

and same thing with "monthOfYear" and "dayOfMonth"

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's worth fussing about with anything in the model, play can do this all in the controller, it's a bit of logic but should be no big deal in a smaller app. Assuming your select boxes POST numbers in your controller and you send other user stuff that mapped properly by name to user properties:

```
public static void save(User user, String day, String month, String year) {
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MMddyy");
    Date birthDate = formatter.parse(month + day + year);
    user.birthDate = birthDate;
    user.save();
}
```